# how to change value in map.continer child class

Tags: matlab, oop

i  have this superClass

```
classdef SysSignal<handle
%SIGNALP Summary of this class goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public )



    SetOfSignal = containers.Map('KeyType','char', 'ValueType', 'any')

end



methods
         %constructor
    function sys=SysSignal()

    end

    function sys=adds(sys,varargin)

        %convert form cell to signalup
       for n=1:length(varargin)

        signal=varargin{1,n};

        if isempty(signal.name)
        continue
        else
             %add to the map 
            sys.SetOfSignal(signal.name)= signal;

        end




       end

    end
```

and that child class

```
classdef Signalp<SysSignal
%SIGNALP Summary of this class goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

properties
  name
  lineNo
  color='red'
  sumrole
end


properties  (SetAccess=private,GetAccess=public)

    arrPrice
    LineLength
    LineProportion

end

methods
         %constructor
    function sig=Signalp(varargin)


    end
end
```

end

now i want to change the properties like this:

```
sys=SysSignal;
 s=Signalp;
 s.name='dd';
sys.adds(s) 

 sys.SetOfSignal('dd').sumrole='hello'
```

but i get that error :

??? Error using ==> subsasgn
Only one level of indexing is supported by a containers.Map.

how can i change the values from the superClass?

Comment: does that work `dd = sys.SetOfSignal('dd'); dd.sumrole='hello'` ?

Comment: Thanks, but how can that be? Create a new variable affect existing variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to seperate `sys.SetOfSignal('dd').sumrole='hello'` into two statements:

```
dd = sys.SetOfSignal('dd'); 
dd.sumrole='hello'
```

That is because `sys.SetOfSignal('dd').sumrole` doesn't do what you'd intuitively think it does. Indeed the `containers.Map` class overloads the subscripted reference and subscripted assignment operators. In essence they 'intercepts' the `()`, `{}` and `.` operators at the same time (ie `.sumrole` is 'sent' to the map.Containers object - instead of your object!). In my opinion that's a really weird design decision but we must live with it!

Have a look at these links for more info: 
[subsref](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), [subsasgn](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html)

Answer (score 1):

gregswiss's answer is correct, except that accessing the containers map creates a copy, so you finish by replacing the old value with the new modified one

```
dd = sys.SetOfSignal('dd'); 
dd.sumrole='hello'
sys.SetOfSignal('dd') = dd;
```

Comment: This is correct in general. But OP’s container contains objects of a class that derives from `handle`, and thus all copies reference the same data; changing one copy changes all other copies too.